# Why it keeps looping even i try to stop it?

Tags: java

I am supposed to write a program that asks the user "Do you love java?" and keep prompting the user for an answer.If the user enters "yes" or "no",print "thank you" and quit the program.Otherwise,print "try again" and then prompt user again.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Questionaire{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Do you love java? > ");
        String output=sc.nextLine();

        while(!output.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || !output.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){

            System.out.println("Try again!");
            System.out.print("Do you love java? > ");
            output=sc.nextLine();
            if(output.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || output.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
                System.out.println("Thank you!");
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Read through the comments and attempt it on my own again.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Questionaire{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Do you love java? > ");
        String output=sc.nextLine();

        while(!output.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || !output.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
            if(output.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || output.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
                System.out.println("Thank you!");
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Try again!");
            System.out.print("Do you love java? > ");
            output=sc.nextLine();

        }



    }
}
```

And i got it!!!Thanks people!

Comment: It keeps looping even i type yes or no

Comment: It runs as expected for me.

Comment: If the user enters "yes" or "no",print "thank you" and quit the program.Mine doesn't quit

Comment: Oh God.  You evaluated the same boolean statement twice.  You shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: But i got my output.You mean that is wrong?The corrected version i attempted again.Are u referring that?

Comment: Why don't you do `while(true)` for the while loop in the second example? That way, it will always run until you reach the `break;` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactored the code, this should work for you. Using `do-while` the code will always execute once but if output is yes or no it does not loop through again.

```
public class Questionaire{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        String output;

        do{

            System.out.print("Do you love java? > ");
            output=sc.nextLine();

            if(output.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || output.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
                System.out.println("Thank you!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Try again!");
            }

        }while(!output.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !output.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))

    }
}
```

Comment: Was reading and trying out with your codes.It is the most helpful answer but i cant get the while with the &&.I was using ||.Can you explain why do you need to use &&?

Comment: I was reading up on de morgan theorem whereby it is said that !(a||b)==> !a && !b .But it does not make sense to me because i thought output must meet either one of the condition instead of both at a time?

Comment: So the `while` statement requires a Boolean and will repeat if `True` and not repeat if `False`. The `&&` means "And Also". So you have two NOT conditions which both must evaluate to True (i.e., it is NOT equal) for the loop to exit. Basically this is saying: If Output is NOT equal to "yes" and also Output is NOT equal to "no" then return `True` causing the loop to continue. So if Output equals "yes" or Output equals "No" this test will fail and return `False` causing the loop to end.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(!output.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || !output.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
```

condition should be changed to

```
while(!output.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !output.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
```

Also you will have to add a if block outside your while to handle first input case.

Reason:

Case 1: Suppose you enter "ABC". Now

It is not equal to "yes" = true

It is not equal to "No" = True (This is not evaluated due to use of short circuit OR). This case works fine.

Case 2: Suppose you enter "Yes". now

It is not equal to "yes" = false

It is not equal to "No" = True.

By boolean Algebra : False OR True evaluates to True.Hence Indefinite loop.

Comment: I don't see a justification to change it to `&&`.  If I enter `foo` for the first input, I'll enter the loop; if I enter `bar` in for the second input, I'll stay in the loop.  It reads like it works as intended.

Comment: Okay.  I see a justification to include `&&`, but you've made incorrect assumptions about boolean operators.  If you enter "ABC", it's not equal to "yes", so it enters the loop.  If you enter "Yes", it is not equal to "yes", so it enters the loop.  The other side isn't evaluated, since it is short-circuiting boolean logic.  The only case in which the right side is evaluated is when the string is equal to "yes", and that will cause the loop to occur again.

Comment: In the case that I have outlined the other side is evaluated. If the first case were true then the other side would not have been evaluated.

Comment: Right.  Yet *you claim it is in case one.*  That's the part I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple approach where `while loop` runs until `yes or no` is entered. It will only break when user enters `yes or no` so print the `Thank you!` in the **end**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Do you love java? > ");
    String output = sc.nextLine();

    while(!(output.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || output.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))) {
        System.out.println("Try again!");
        System.out.print("Do you love java? > ");
        output = sc.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println("Thank you!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try it  (It easier to handle then original program)

```
String output = "";
 while (!output.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || !output.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
     System.out.print("Do you love java? > ");
     output = sc.nextLine();
     if (output.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || output.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
         System.out.println("Thank you!");
         break;
     } else {
         System.out.println("Try again!");
     }
 }
```

Comment: I would simplify to a `do-while` loop. Just makes for a more logical and readable code since output the loop will always have to complete one time and it eliminates the unnecessary `break` statement.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution for your class is going to be:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Questionaire{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Do you love java? > ");
        String output=sc.nextLine();
        while(true){ // Keep doing this forever
            if(output.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || output.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){ // If the user enters yes or enters no
                System.out.println("Thank you!"); //Print thank you
                break; // Exit
            } else {
                System.out.println("Try again"); //Print try again
                output = sc.nextLine(); // Get new user input.
            }
        }
        sc.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Now you are making this more complicated to solve the problem. The correct code strategy for the requirement indicated is a `do-while` loop.

Comment: @Nicknow:  "Correct" is subjective.  There is at least one other way that this could be done.

Comment: I think I find Bhushan's solution above the most elegant. The do-while has the condition evaluated twice.

Comment: This could be one of the solution but obviously not the best. (I am not the downvoter)

Comment: @ArjunRao - Bhushan's solution has the condition evaluated twice (once before entering the loop for the first time and then again after the first loop to determine if it needs to run again.) Just because it is only written once doesn't mean it only executes once. I would also point out Bhushan's code has two statements repeated while the `do-while` code only has one statement repeated.

Comment: Not true. Let us say the user enters "a" 10 times and then enters "yes", in Bhushan's code, the condition is evaluated 13 times. In your code, it is executed 22 times. 1 condition in the if 1 in the while.

Comment: Good point. The solution though is to drop the `while` condition and just have `while(true);` and then add a `break;` after the `System.out.println("Thank you!");` line. That eliminates the double evaluation issue and doesn't have any code being duplicated.

Comment: Which makes it almost equal to my solution except that I'm using a "while" instead of a do-while. :)